# How can i add item to list but not the ones are already added

Tags: dart

I am trying to add unique items to a list so that I avoid repetition of them.

```dart
List listOne = ['a','b','c','d'];
List listTwo = ['a','b'];
    
listTwo.add(/* Here i need to add : ['e','f','a','b']*/) // but avoid 'a','b' because they already exist.
```

I have done it by making a loop like following

```dart
for(final test in listOne ) {
  if(!listTwo.contains(test)) {
    listTwo.add(test);
  }
}
```

But I don't think it is a good way for big data.

Is there any good way for handling this?

Comment: Use a [`Set`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set-class.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
listOne = ['a','b','c','d'];
listTwo = ['a','b'];
mergedArray = new Set(listOne .concat(listTwo ));
```

Comment: `Error: Setter not found: 'listOne'.`

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List listOne = ['a','b','c','d'];
List listTwo = ['a','b'];
Set listTwoSet = new  Set.from(listTwo);
listTwoSet.addAll(listOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to use list,

```
// check if item is present in current-list or not.
bool isNotPresent = list
                .where((oldElement) => oldElement.key == newElement!.key)
                .isEmpty;
            if (isNotPresent) { // add now
              list.add(newElement);
              
            }
```